# Crack in a post footing

Tags: concrete, post, footings

I recently saw a lamp post that was newly installed in **public place** (Not my post).

It looked like a 6x6 with the footing poured around it. On top, the lamp extends out 3+ feet in one direction, so there's torque on the footing.

I noticed a crack in the footing extending from the corner of the post to the edge of the footing, then down to almost the ground. The gap is about 1/16" of an inch.

How bad is this? I ask because concrete does poorly under tension unless it's reinforced, but this shouldn't happen if it's reinforced, and torque could definitely cause this.

[image]

Comment: you allowed the concrete to dry too fast. How many times did you water it during the drying process ? or did you soak the ground before pouring concrete ?

Comment: It's not actually my footing. I saw it out in public somewhere.

Comment: So why are you posting that ? Still my advice stands.

Comment: I was curious how it happens and how bad it is.

Comment: I already explained how it happens.

Comment: Depends on the location.  If somewhere it gets cool and it rains, then freezes, it might have a short life as a support.

Comment: Common cracking location as it is the thinnest portion of the concrete.  Depending on what the job is of that portion of the concrete it could be purely cosmetic issue and totally non structural.  One would need to look at the design.  Is there reinforcing, how deep is the footing, how deep is the pole embedded, is the pole anchored by some other means, and probably more than a few other factors.  Without knowing the details, its not possible to say if this is a structural concern or not.  However this is the first step in the inevitable deterioration and shortening of the life span.